# maximum number of faces with n lines

Tags: surfaces

I was wondering a formula F(n) to guess the maximum number of faces made with n lines, for example:

- with 1 line, we cant create a face;

  F(n) = 0;
- with 2 lines, we also cant create a face

  F(n) = 0;
- with 3 lines, the best we can do is a triangle;

  F(n) = 1;
- with 4 lines, the best we can do is split that triangle in 2 and cross another line, making 3 faces...

  F(n) = 3;

Searching about that, I found the Lazy caterer's sequence, that given a number n of lines, it divides a 2D space in at most  $\frac{ n² + n + 2}{2}$ parts, but some of this parts are not faces, they are just a space created by lines that do not close (for example, there are 4 of this spaces if you cross 2 lines, and they are not faces).

So I thought:

- if the lines go to the infinity, all n lines together will create 2n of this spaces that are not faces

  [suppose you look at them from a distance so far that the part where occurs the intersections seems to be a point, then all the lines would be crossing a single point and then, creating 2n spaces between them]
- if there are n spaces, then the number of faces would be:

  $$ F(n) = \frac {n^2 + n + 2}{2} - 2n $$  that is

  $$ F(n) = \frac {n^2 - 3n + 2}{2} $$

Am I right? If so, how can I prove that? I'd like to try with induction, but I dont know how...

Comment: Looks OK to me, provided you know the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_caterer's_sequence#Proof) for the lazy caterer's sequence.